# sent last id inserted variable to another page in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, last-insert-id

in this code i have to insert some value in DB, then i have to take last id inserted in DB and sent it to another page to show the value of that id row. here is my code for insert data in DB :

```
try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=resume", "root", "");
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql_basic = "INSERT INTO user_basic_info (first_name,last_name,address,profile_pic,resume_file)
VALUES ('$FirstName','$LastName','$Address','$pic_destination','$resume_destination')";

    $con->exec($sql_basic);
    $last_id = $con->$lastInsertId();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql_basic . "<br>" . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
}

$con = null;

header('Location: DB-Read.php?id=' . $last_id);
```

in another php page i have to take `$last_id` and use it. here is my code:

```
try {
    $user_id = $id;
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=resume", "root", "");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT first_name FROM user_basic_info where user_id = ".$user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo "this is username: " . $result;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;

header('Location: show-edit.php?id=' . $last_id);
```

first of all `$lastInsertId()` not working !!
after that, is my way true to take `$last_id` from first page ?

Comment: you can use `$_SESSION`

Comment: Check the braces in the catch statement. This maybe causing an error message that you are not seeing.

Comment: You can set the last inserted id in SESSION['id'] and can retrieve it on next page and after usage you can unset this. SESSION is more secure way to pass database ids.

Answer (score 1):

`lastInsertId` is a method of the `PDO` object. You need to call `$conn->lastInsertId();`.

Your given syntax `$conn->$lastInsertId();` is valid, however, it does not do, what you are expecting. It considers `$lastInsertId` to be a variable containing the method name to be called. The following example would work as well:

```
$method_name = 'lastInsertId';
$conn->$method_name();
```

*Be aware that your solution enables anyone to fetch any row of your table. Consider using sessions.*

Answer (score -1):

**TRY THIS:**
**use session:**

```
try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=resume", "root", "");
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $sql_basic = "INSERT INTO user_basic_info    (first_name,last_name,address,profile_pic,resume_file)
VALUES     ('$FirstName','$LastName','$Address','$pic_destination','$resume_destination')";

   $con->exec($sql_basic);
   $_SESSION['id'] = $con->lastInsertId(); //it's a method
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql_basic . "<br>" . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
$con = null;

header('Location: DB-Read.php?id=' . $last_id);
```

Now use this code

```
try {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=resume", "root", "");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT first_name FROM user_basic_info where user_id = ".$user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo "this is username: " . $result;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;

header('Location: show-edit.php?id=' . $last_id);
```